# Scope of Features at different level

Tags: 2013, scope, feature-scope

Sorry for posting another "Broad" question in the community but I really want to know

> "What are the Scope of features at Web Application level, Site Collection Level
>   and Site Level?"

What I know is that Scope of Features generally refers to the "Effective locations up to which a feature would be affecting a site."

What I mean to say is: If I activate a feature of a site, that feature will be affecting only up to that Site Level but not to any other sites (excluding sub sites), or site collections, and so on. But once a feature is activated at Web application level, it will take effect for all the site collections and sites and sub sites under it.

But still I have been asked to know to get a brief idea about Scope and the question in Blockquote. Is it like things what I know is wrong or am I missing something? Even if is, then do post the correct answer. And if you think, there is anything else you can add, Then please do it! Because without understanding the Scope, I couldn't proceed to any of the SharePoint Tasks and Projects.

This is the [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-feature-scopes-activation/) which I referred to for this information:

Also, at site collection level, we have both the options which are 1)Manage Site Features 2)Manage Site Collection Features. So, what's the relation between those two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Features scopes are defined as

**Farm Level**

---

- A farm level feature, as the name suggests, is something that affects the whole farm, for example provisioning a custom timer job or deploying a Business Connectivity Services model.
- Farm Scoped feature can be activated at the Farm level.
- It can contain number of element like application logic etc which can
  be applicable anywhere within deployment. It contacts links to
  /_layouts pages and files, /_admin pages etc.
- It can be activated by STSADM command like ” stsadm “o installfeature
  “name FeatureFolderName
- Alternatively open Manage Farm Features from Central Administrator
  Central Administrator -> Operations -> Manage Application Features
  and click activate. Farm scope feature will be activated
  automatically once it is installed on server.

**Web Application Level:**

---

- A web application feature can be activated so that it only affects a
  single web application, and a typical example is a feature that
  modifies the **`web.config`** file.
- Web Application Scoped feature can be activated at the Web
  application level.
- It can contains item like administrative web application links,
  delegate control registrations, document forms registration etc.
- It can be activated by STSADM command like ” stsadm “o installfeature
  “name FeatureFolderName “url http://sharepointserver
- Alternatively open Manage Web Application Features from Central
  Administrator Central Administrator -> Application Management ->
  Manage Application Features and click activate.

**Site Level:**

---

- A site scoped feature can be activated so that it only affects a site
  collection, an example being the deployment of a master page to the
  master pages catalogue.
- Site Collection Scoped feature can be activated at the site
  collection level.
- It can contains item that can apply to Site Collection as a whole
  like content types that are shared across the site collection, as
  well as items that can be activated per site for e.g. List Instances,
  Event Receivers, Custom Actions etc
- It can be activated by STSADM command like ” stsadm “o installfeature
  “name FeatureFolderName “url
  http://sharepointserver/site/sitecollectionname
- Alternatively open site features page by site actions -> site
  settings -> modify all site settings ->site features and click
  activate.

**Web Level:**

---

- Finally, a web scoped feature can be activated for a single site, for
  instance setting the default master page for that site.
- Web Site Scoped feature can be activated at individual Web site
  level.
- List Instances, Event Receivers, Custom Actions etc are the custom
  elements for Website scope features.
- It can be activated by STSADM command like ” stsadm “o installfeature
  “name FeatureFolderName “url http://sharepointserver/site/subsite
- Alternatively open site features page by site actions -> site
  settings -> modify all site settings ->site features and click
  activate.

References

- [Understanding Features and Feature Scope](http://www.pritambaldota.com/index.php/understanding-features-and-feature-scope-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Using Features and Solutions to Deploy your SharePoint Customizations](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-tools/using-features-and-solutions-to-deploy-your-sharepoint-customizations/)

Comment: at site collection level, we have both the options which are
1)Manage Site Features 
2)Manage Site Collection Features.
So, what's the relation between those two?

Comment: Please add this comment into your question. I'll update my answer

Comment: I did. Can you update your answer please?

Answer (score 2):

What you have understood is correct.. Scope defines the range of area where your feature will effects on getting activated. If you activate at parent level(web app) it will be available at child site( site collection and subsites ). ..while if you define just a site as a scope..it will be just that site and no other site.

Comment: Ankit, this is not necessarily true. Some features are not available in child sites (as you call them) even if you activate a feature on a web application level. It depends.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis Can you please show me an example? I would do anything for you if you could provide me a set of such features.

Comment: A custom timer job with a scope of Web Application. Anyone can correct me if I am wrong, but that Timer Job will only be available to active on a Web Application level. I might be reading Ankit's comment in a wrong way..

Comment: Paul you are right.. We can have a timer job based on the Web App scope.. But this particular timer job will be applicable to all site collection listed under that web app or to a particular sitecollection inside that web app. depending on the LockType value.